# [Xamarin.Forms][Android] Change back and next color in navigation

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I' have some navigation page and I want to override the color for the back button and my next button ( **ToolbarItem** )

I Already tried **BarTextColor** property but it change color for all navigation header text.

It's done in IOS, but I' not able to find a solution for android.

It works perfectly for the title but not for the Icons.

Here my code :

```
protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

    var page = this.Element as NavigationPage;
    if (page != null && toolbar != null)
    {
        toolbar.SetTitleTextColor(Color.Black.ToAndroid());

        if (toolbar.NavigationIcon != null)
            toolbar.NavigationIcon.SetColorFilter(Color.Green.ToAndroid(), Android.Graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.Multiply);

        if (toolbar.OverflowIcon != null)
            toolbar.OverflowIcon.SetColorFilter(Color.Green.ToAndroid(), Android.Graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.Multiply);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I' have some navigation page and I want to override the color for the back button and my next button ( ToolbarItem )

Your next button is a `ToolbarItem`, which is defined by yourself. So it won't be a problem for you to customize it. The difficult part lies in the back button, because it is offered by `Xamarin.Forms`. You need to override the `NavigationPageRenderer` to change the color:

```
public class MyNavigationPageRenderer : NavigationPageRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<NavigationPage> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            var navController = (INavigationPageController)e.NewElement;
            navController.PushRequested += NavController_PushRequested;
            navController.PopRequested += NavController_PopRequested;
        }
    }

    private void NavController_PopRequested(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.Internals.NavigationRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(220), () =>
        {
            ChangeIconColor();
            return false;
        });
    }

    private void NavController_PushRequested(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.Internals.NavigationRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        ChangeIconColor();
    }

    private void ChangeIconColor()
    {
        int count = this.ViewGroup.ChildCount;

        var toolbar = GetToolbar();

        if (toolbar.NavigationIcon != null)
        {
            var drawable = (toolbar.NavigationIcon as DrawerArrowDrawable);
            drawable.Color = Resource.Color.material_grey_850;//set the navigation icon color here
        }
    }

    private AToolbar GetToolbar()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.ViewGroup.ChildCount; i++)
        {
            var child = this.ViewGroup.GetChildAt(i);
            if (child is AToolbar)
            {
                return (AToolbar)child;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

A little explanation to the codes above: `PushRequest` and `PopRequest` fires when you push and pop a new page to the navigation page and it is the perfect time for you to customize the existing Toolbar's `NavigationIcon`. So first find the Toolbar using `GetToolbar` then change the icon color by `ChangeIconColor`.